# Get Common substring between list and string Flutter

Tags: dart

**Sample 1:**

```
tags = ['what','play','school']
string = "what is your name?"

Output = ['what']
```

**Sample 2:**

```
tags = ['what is','play football','school','food']
string = "what is your school name? Do you play football there?"

Output = ['what is','school',"play football"]
```

How can I achieve this in flutter?

Answer (score 3):

You can use where to find all words present in the string.

```
void main() {
  List<String> tags = ['what', 'play', 'school'];
  String _string = "what is your name?";

  List<String> commonWords = [...tags.where(_string.contains)];
  print(commonWords); // [what]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```dart
void main() {
  var tags = ['what is', 'play football', 'school', 'food'];
  String string = "what is your school name? Do you play football there?";

  print(tags.where((element)=> string.contains(element)));
}
```

Comment: Be aware that your solution are returning `Iterable` which you are then printing. This is "fine" right now because `tags` are rather short. But if you increase the length to e.g. `var tags = ['what is', 'play football', 'school', 'food','what is', 'play football', 'what is', 'play football', 'school'];`, it will start printing: `(what is, play football, school, what is, ..., play football, school)` since Dart will automatically limit the amount of data being output from `Iterable` when using the default `toString()` which is done by `print`.